# Ripple effect over colored ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamic

I have a dynamically created ImageButton. Here is my code -

```
ImageButton bar = new ImageButton(this);

... //some code

parentView.addView(bar);
```

Ripple effect appears when I click the ImageButton. But when I add the following line -

```
bar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

The ripple effect doesn't appear anymore. Is there any way to make the ripple effect appear on a colored ImageButton?

---

By ripple effect, I mean this effect - [click here](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/raw/master/demo.gif) (I'm sorry but I cannot add the image here as gifs are not supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
bar.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

You need to check what MODE would be apopriate, because i don't have big experience with this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working. But only problem is that the size of the image button changes. The imageButton becomes smaller and edges get rounded. Is there any way to prevent that?